# scanf() pause loop in multiple line input

Tags: c, input, char, scanf, getchar

I have some problem with my input when using **scanf()**. I'm trying to input a bunch of individual chars into a 2-dim array of chars. Everything works fine until the **last line** (*as soon as I enter the inner for-loop a last time*) where the program halts, and wait for me to press enter, then it works as intended again and finishes. How can i get the program to continue without me having to press enter? Note: This code is just a extraction of the program containing the problem for readability.

**Input:** First two integers are the rows and columns of the following matrix starting on a newline containing chars without spaces, as shown in comment in code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
char matrix[100][100];
int nrows;  
int ncols;  

scanf("%d %d", &nrows, &ncols);

for (int i = 0; i<nrows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j<ncols; j++) {
        scanf(" %c", &matrix[i][j]);
        printf("[%d][%d]\n", i, j);     //to check pause
    }
}
return 0;
}

//10 20
//%%%&&%%%%%&&&%&%&&&%
//%%%&&%%%%%&&&%&%&&&%
//%%%&&%%%%%&&&%&%&&&%
//%%%&&%%%%%&&&%&%&&&%
//%%%&&%%%%%&&&%&%&&&%
//%%%&&%%%%%&&&%&%&&&%
//%%%&&%%%%%&&&%&%&&&%
//%%%&&%%%%%&&&%&%&&&%
//%%%&&%%%%%&&&%&%&&&%
//%%%&&%%%%%&&&%&%&&&%
```

Have been looking for a fix on this for ages and tried my way forward, when using `getchar()` and a while containing both '`\n`' and EOF provided the same identical problem.

Thank you in advance

Comment: If you don't have to press "Enter" how will the code know that the input for the previous entries is complete? At the last entry, the code waited for a newline just like the other entries.

Comment: Cannot reproduce, entering last line behaves like entering the others.

Comment: Actually, the code does not care at all about newlines/enter. The non-whitespace characters can be entered with just a single "enter" at the end or with an "enter" for each character.

Comment: Please provide a sample input, keypress by keypress and explain the output and what "forces" you to use "enter" for the last line.

Comment: The `scanf` format `" %c"` will skip whitespace, so you are not expecting any whitespace characters as valid input. Have you considered using `scanf(" %s", matrix[i]);` and remove the `j` loop?

Comment: "How can i get the program to continue without me having to press enter?" --> `stdin` is typically line buffered.  Nothing is given from the keyboard to `scanf()` until `'\n'`, keyboard buffer full or closed. So close input rather than <enter>

Comment: `getchar()` will not help - buffering still applies.  Non-standard `getch():` will work to "How can i get the program to continue without me having to press enter?"

Comment: @WeatherVane `scanf(" %s", matrix[i])` is akin to suggesting `gets(matrix[i])`.  Neither are recommended.

Comment: @chux mybad I skipped over that, because dealing with a recovery from, say, `scanf(" %99s", matrix[i]);` was too much for a comment.

Comment: You can press "Enter" after every character if you like, but you'll have to press "Enter" *at least* once. I can't understand at all what the problem is. Are you expecting the last line to be entered without any newline? Think about it, suppose you were entering numbers: when you type a `1` the system needs to know that you aren't then going to type `2` to give `12` and not just grab the first number, ditto with a string input. The system isn't going to think to itself "ah he is entering single letters and I know he needs exactly `n` more".

Comment: @Yunnosch You are right and I managed to find the problem to the input. I actually only press enter once but the program starts as soon as i paste the entire input.. Thank you all for the help and comments